# Why doesn't piping grep output into xargs work with color?

Tags: linux, bash, grep, xargs

I have a strange issue. My `grep` has colored output, and if I do something like this:

```
grep -lr '80' /etc/apache2/sites-available/|xargs ls
```

I got:

```
ls: cannot access /etc/apache2/sites-available/default: No such file or directory
```

But if I add `--colour=none` to `grep`, everything is OK.

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be a broken alias.
Take a look at your **/home/USERNAME/.bashrc (/root/.bashrc)**
If you see a

> alias grep="grep -ARG1 -ARG2"

remove it or customize it as you like.

Comment: I don't think that's the OP's problem, but either way it's easier and more accurate to just type `alias`. It outputs all aliases in effect.

Comment: There's a good chance that an alias such as `alias grep="grep --color always"` is involved.

Comment: Yes, in this bashrc I have --always, that's the problem here.

Comment: Well, if it was the solution to your problem, i'm glad i could help. And please confirm my answer as the solution by checking the check on the left of this post.

Answer (score 3):

> Where am I wrong?

Here's the problem: You're parsing the output of a command that spits out file names. You should *never* do that. And if you do, you need to make sure the output is well-formed and file names are properly delimited.<sup>*</sup>

Usually piping file names to `xargs` "just works" and it's a "good enough" solution, but it will not work if the command is inserting color control characters into its stdout. The output is meant to be readable for humans, on a terminal, and not by other commands.

The real question is: Why are you doing `| xargs ls` when `grep` already prints the file names?

<sub>* For example, `find … -print0 | xargs -0` is a construct that delimits files with the only character that isn't allowed in file names, so you'll be safe there. However, in most of these cases `find … -exec` will work just as well.</sub>

Comment: Thank you, got it. ls after xargs is a an example, real command is ...|xargs sed -i 's/8080/80/g'

Comment: I see! If you need to replace every occurrence of 80 with 8080, why not run `perl -pi -e 's/8080/80/g' /etc/apache2/sites-available/*`?

Comment: My skills in perl is not good, so far :)

Answer (score 1):

There are typically[0] 3 arguments that can be used with the `--color` option to `grep`: "auto", "always", and "none". It seems like your `grep` may be aliased to use `--color always`, in which case the ANSI escape codes used to colorize the output are interfering with `ls`'s ability to show them. When you use `--color=none`, you tell `grep` not to use these, fixing your problem. The `auto` option is a good compromise: it says to use color when the output is a terminal, but not to if the output is a file or pipeline, or generally something else where the ANSI codes will not work as intended.

That said, slhck is right and you probably don't need to be piping the output of `grep` to anything in this case, but it's good to understand the color-related issues for the future.

[0] I say typically, because my man page says you can use "never", "always", and "auto". Perhaps "none" and "never" are synonyms.